# Super Slow C++ For Loop

Tags: c++

While parsing binary data I am running into something I didn't expect, the for loop is really slow compared to a similar method in C#. Previous to this I have already read from the file into the `std::vector<unsigned char> BufferedLine` and all this has to do is break up a buffer of 300 chars into 80 columns of various widths.

```
    char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
    std::vector<unsigned char> CurrentColumnBytes(ColumnBytes.ColumnWidth);
    int arraySize = CurrentColumnBytes.size();
    int start=ColumnBytes.StartingPosition;
    int width=ColumnBytes.ColumnWidth + ColumnBytes.StartingPosition;
    stopwatch<> sw;
    for (int C = start; C < width; ++C)
    {
        int Index = C - ColumnBytes.StartingPosition;
        CurrentColumnBytes[Index] = BufferedLine[C];
    }
    std::cout << "Elapsed: " << duration_cast<double>(sw.elapsed()) << '\n';
```

This is wrapped in another for loop that performs this same thing per column of data. For each cell it outputs:

```
Elapsed: 0.0029621
Elapsed: 0.0012005
Elapsed: 0.0012492
Elapsed: 0.0010724
Elapsed: 0.0010622
Elapsed: 0.0009512
Elapsed: 0.0012072
```

That may not seem like a long time, but that is per CELL of a database, meaning it is only parsing about 25 rows per second. When I measured it for the entire line, it is around `0.07` on average.

Here is the relevant portion of the `Byte` struct:

```
struct Byte
{
    std::string  DataType;
    int  ColumnWidth;
    int StartingPosition;
    std::string Column;
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;

    int size() { 
        return this->data.size();
    }
};
```

Normally there is additional processing that happens below where the stopwatch is printed, but for the purposes of debugging and performance testing I commented it all out.  It was compiled in VS2019 with optimizations enabled on a PC with 24 2.4GHz cores and 64GB RAM with the following switches:

```
/JMC /permissive- /MP /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\BitBucket\boost_1_71_0\stage\lib" /I"C:\BitBucket\boost_1_71_0\" /ZI /Gm- /O1 /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Altering the optimization types gives me the following times. These are per full row, rather than just per cell as above.

```
//O1
Elapsed: 0.0760841
Elapsed: 0.0479458
Elapsed: 0.102819
Elapsed: 0.0902831
Elapsed: 0.0458162
Elapsed: 0.045791
Elapsed: 0.0464516
Elapsed: 0.0466347
Elapsed: 0.0457104

//O2    
Elapsed: 0.0913771
Elapsed: 0.0419886
Elapsed: 0.042406
Elapsed: 0.0435289
Elapsed: 0.0402844
Elapsed: 0.0447555
Elapsed: 0.0411286

//Ox
Elapsed: 0.0655737
Elapsed: 0.0413363
Elapsed: 0.04166
Elapsed: 0.0405113
Elapsed: 0.0398387
Elapsed: 0.0399873
Elapsed: 0.0386572
Elapsed: 0.0376599
Elapsed: 0.0427373
Elapsed: 0.0380113
Elapsed: 0.0400754
```

When I do these same steps in C#, I was getting nearly 200,000 cells/second. Is there an issue with my C++ that stands out? I have asked before about datatypes and performance, not sure if the unsigned char vector has something to do with this or not, but that seems like a really long time for essentially copying a few bytes from one array to another.

Stopwatch definition:

```
template <typename Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
class stopwatch
{
    typename Clock::time_point last_;

public:
    stopwatch()
        : last_(Clock::now())
    {}

    void reset()
    {
        *this = stopwatch();
    }

    typename Clock::duration elapsed() const
    {
        return Clock::now() - last_;
    }

    typename Clock::duration tick()
    {
        auto now = Clock::now();
        auto elapsed = now - last_;
        last_ = now;
        return elapsed;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Rep, typename Period>
T duration_cast(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    return duration.count() * static_cast<T>(Period::num) / static_cast<T>(Period::den);
}
```

### UPDATE

I got a working example up on Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VIvardJNAMKzSbMf

For some reason it is running with the following times:

```
Elapsed: 0.00115457
Elapsed: 0.000815412
Elapsed: 0.000814636
```

But the exact same code on my PC is taking:

```
Elapsed: 0.05275
Elapsed: 0.02782
Elapsed: 0.0283161
```

Comment: Debug or Release and compilation switches please.

Comment: `/O1` is a low [optimization setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=vs-2019), you might try `/O2`

Comment: Not sure how you're getting `0.07` as an average for the given figures, they're all `0.00-something`, ten times faster. Even if we round them up to `0.005`, that's 250 cells per second, not 25. Now that may *still* be slow, I'm just pointing out the possible miscalculation.

Comment: @paxdiablo I was just including the first few loops through, there are 80 columns. I updated the question to include times for the whole line.

Comment: Looking at that code, I'm wondering about the quality of your stopwatch.

Comment: Unrelated: `width` is a confusing name for a _one beyond end_ index variable.

Comment: It is a holdover from my C# which reads as: `byte[] currentColumnBytes = currentLineBytes.Skip(startingPosition).Take(width).ToArray();`

Comment: It's hard to benchmark isolated code with optimization btw, because optimizers might just optimize whole chunks of code that has no side effects...

Comment: For performance profiling, it would be helpful to have a [mcve].  My own cobbled together code appears to be about a million times faster than the performance you are seeing.  That could be dependent on the hardware involve, or that I used Clang++ with `-O2` and yours was compiled with VS2019 with `/O1`.  Or that I'm using C# on Mono, and you (presumably) used C# on .NET.

Comment: I updated the question with an example I got working. For some reason it is much faster on Wandbox than it is on my own PC, which should not be. My PC has dual Xeon v3 2.4Ghz with 64GB RAM using NVMe SSD drives. I am very new to C++, so I am still trying to learn what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked through it some more and got it working on another question: [C++ Perfomance Per Compiler, 200 times slower than C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531621/c-perfomance-per-compiler-200-times-slower-than-c-sharp)

Part of it was reworking the loop, part was the compiler being used. I was able to get C++ processing the file at around 50,000 rows per second with 80 columns per row. I reworked the entire workflow to make sure it didn't have to backtrack at all. I first read the entire file into ByteArray and then would go over it line by line by moving data from one array to another rather than specifying each byte in a for loop. I then used a map to store the data.

```
stopwatch<> sw;
    while (CurrentLine < TotalLines)
    {
        int BufferOffset = CurrentLine * LineLength;
        std::move(ByteArray + BufferOffset, ByteArray + BufferOffset + LineLength, LineByteArray);
        for (int i = 0; TotalColumns > i + 1; ++i)
        {
            int ThisStartingPosition = StartingPosition[i];
            int ThisWidth = ColumnWidths[i];
            std::uint8_t* CurrentColumnBytes;
            CurrentColumnBytes = new uint8_t[ThisWidth];
            {
                std::move(LineByteArray + ThisStartingPosition, LineByteArray + ThisStartingPosition + ThisWidth, CurrentColumnBytes);
                ResultMap[CurrentLine][i] = Format(CurrentColumnBytes, ThisWidth, DataType[i]);
            }
        }
        CurrentLine++;
    }
    std::cout << "Processed" << CurrentLine << " lines in : " << duration_cast<double>(sw.elapsed()) << '\n';
```