# C++ Perfomance Per Compiler, 200 times slower than C#

Tags: c#, c++, gcc

I was dealing with some performance issues which I discussed in this question: [Super Slow C++ For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494786/super-slow-c-for-loop)

I have a simple program I wrote to parse binary data. I tested it locally on 2 computers.

```
1. Dual 6 core 2.4GHz Xeon V3, 64GB RAM, NVMe SSD
2. Dual 4 core 3.5GHz Xeon V3, 64GB RAM, NVMe SSD
```

Here is some of the code(rest is on Wandbox https://wandbox.org/permlink/VIvardJNAMKzSbMf):

```
string HexRow="";
for (int i=b; i<HexLineLength+b;i++){
    HexRow+= incomingData[i];
}

std::vector<unsigned char> BufferedLine=HexToBytes(HexRow);
stopwatch<> sw;
for (int i = 0; 80 >= i; ++i)
{
    Byte ColumnBytes;
    for (auto it = columns["data"][i].begin(); it != columns["data"][i].end(); ++it)
    {
        try {
            if (it.key() == "Column") { ColumnBytes.Column = it.value().get<std::string>();}
            else if (it.key() == "DataType") { ColumnBytes.DataType = it.value().get<std::string>();}
            else if (it.key() == "StartingPosition") { ColumnBytes.StartingPosition = it.value().get<int>();}
            else if (it.key() == "ColumnWidth") { ColumnBytes.ColumnWidth = it.value().get<int>();}
        }
        catch (...) {}
    }

    char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
    std::vector<unsigned char> CurrentColumnBytes(ColumnBytes.ColumnWidth);
    int arraySize = CurrentColumnBytes.size();

    for (int C = ColumnBytes.StartingPosition; C < ColumnBytes.ColumnWidth + ColumnBytes.StartingPosition; ++C)
    {
        int Index = C - ColumnBytes.StartingPosition;
        CurrentColumnBytes[Index] = BufferedLine[C-1];
    }
}
std::cout << "Elapsed: " << duration_cast<double>(sw.elapsed()) << '\n';
```

### PC 1

Compiling on PC 1 with Visual Studio using the following flags:

```
/O2 /JMC /permissive- /MP /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /sdl /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Output:

```
Elapsed: 0.0913771
Elapsed: 0.0419886
Elapsed: 0.042406
```

Using Clang with the following: `clang main.cpp -O3` outputs:

```
Elapsed: 0.036262
Elapsed: 0.0174264
Elapsed: 0.0170038
```

Compiling with GCC from MinGW `gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)` using these switches `gcc main.cpp -lstdc++ -O3` gives the following time:

```
Elapsed: 0.019841
Elapsed: 0.0099643
Elapsed: 0.0094552
```

### PC 2

I get with Visual Studio, still with the /O2

```
Elapsed: 0.054841
Elapsed: 0.03543
Elapsed: 0.034552
```

I didn't do Clang and GCC on PC 2, but the improvement wasn't significant enough to resolve my concerns.

## Wandbox

The issue is that the exact same code on Wandbox (https://wandbox.org/permlink/VIvardJNAMKzSbMf) executes 10-80 times faster

```
Elapsed: 0.00115457
Elapsed: 0.000815412
Elapsed: 0.000814636
```

Wandbox is using GCC 10.0.0 and c++14. I realize it is likely running on linux, and I couldn't find any way to get GCC 10 to compile on Windows, so I can't test compiling with that version.

## C# - 200X Faster

This is a rewrite of a C# application I wrote, which operates so much faster:

```
Elapsed: 0.017424 
Elapsed: 0.0006065 
Elapsed: 0.000733 
Elapsed: 0.0006166 
Elapsed: 0.0004699 

Finished Parsing: 100 Records. Elapsed :0.0082796 at a rate of : 12076/s
```

The C# Method looks like this:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
foreach (dynamic item in TableData.data)  //TableData is a JSON file with the structure definition
{

    string DataType = item.DataType;
    int startingPosition = item.StartingPosition;

    int width = Convert.ToInt32(item.ColumnWidth);
    if (width+startingPosition >= FullLineLength)
    {
        continue;
    }

    byte[] currentColumnBytes = currentLineBytes.Skip(startingPosition).Take(width).ToArray();

   // .....     200 extra lines of processing into ints, dates, strings       ......
   // ..... Even with the extra work, it operates at 1200+ records per second ......

}
sw.Stop();
var seconds = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
sw.Reset();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + seconds);
TempTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

When I started this, I expected huge performance gains by moving code to unmanaged C++ from C#. This is my first C++ project and I am frankly just a bit discouraged about where I am. What can be done to speed up this C++? Do I need to use different datatypes, `malloc`, more / less structs?

It needs to run on Windows, not sure if there is a way to get GCC 10 to work on Windows?

What suggestions do you have for an aspiring C++ Developer?

Comment: Most likely the difference is due to the value orientation of C++ v the reference orientation of C#. If you pass by value large objects with portions in the heap things will be quite slow compared to C#. Especially if move semantics haven't been used. Use `const T&` when passing these in C++ or `T&` if you are mutating the data.

Comment: For more on optimization of C++ programs, a decent reference can be found pdf [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ahanda/optimizing_cpp.pdf). Generally, you want to pass objects by reference or const reference and plain data types(such as int) by value. Most of Chapter 7, especially 7.12-7.15 has more information about the efficiency of different data types, functions, and passing.

Comment: A few things struck me in the code. The vectors are being built up piece by piece and this creates a lot of thrashing. Best to pre-allocate them at declaration time. Also the conversion of ascii hex bytes is going to be slower than molasses. You might consider writing a short function to convert the 2 char he values. Should run a lot faster. The std conversion functions are pretty bad in cases like this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want code that can't be decompiled with ILSpy, so C++ seemed an optimal choice. I also run a PHP website on Linux and was just musing about doing some custom PHP modules in C, but sadly this portion of the application is to be deployed at customers locations and must run on Windows.  I am surprised to hear C++ would be hobbled when nearly every high performance software including databases, video games and so much more are written in C++;

Comment: In addition to the above. The library your using for JSON is not particularly fast https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark#parsing-time many of the compeditors. I suspect C#'s newtonsoft JSON is faster.

@SamVarshavchik Do you have any evidance of this? Microsoft have put alot of hours into MSVC, they also have contributed alot in terms of the STL https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/open-sourcing-msvcs-stl/. I don't think you will find any evidance because microsoft are not the only ones producing compilers for windows. Clang, GCC and Intel all produce compilers.

Comment: Thank you for that tip David. Before I was just storing all values in a `vector<string>`, but to keep the data types true I used the JSON. Normally the datasource is a binary file, not a string of hex, but I wasn't sure how else to provide an online example. MickyD, This isn't the whole program, but it was enough to show the performance problems I was facing. This is my first C++ program, I am learning all about the performance options, and what makes some code more `performant` than another similar block.

Comment: One of the good aspects of C++ is that you are programming close to the metal. But things like destructors click in automatically when you go out of scope. This is great for control of heap usage but C# uses garbage collection and can delay heap cleanup long after objects are no longer in use. Collection will eventually occur with associated delays but is something you have little control over. It's good and it's bad. Just stuff to be aware of in coding and especially benchmarking.

Comment: please include the C++ code here. External links may rot sometime in the future, making the question invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to get C++ processing the file at around 50,000 rows per second with 80 columns per row. I reworked the entire workflow to make sure it didn't have to backtrack at all. I first read the entire file into `ByteArray` and then would go over it line by line by moving data from one array to another rather than specifying each byte in a `for` loop. I then used a `map` to store the data.

```
    stopwatch<> sw;
    while (CurrentLine < TotalLines)
    {
        int BufferOffset = CurrentLine * LineLength;
        std::move(ByteArray + BufferOffset, ByteArray + BufferOffset + LineLength, LineByteArray);
        for (int i = 0; TotalColumns > i + 1; ++i)
        {
            int ThisStartingPosition = StartingPosition[i];
            int ThisWidth = ColumnWidths[i];
            std::uint8_t* CurrentColumnBytes;
            CurrentColumnBytes = new uint8_t[ThisWidth];
            {
                std::move(LineByteArray + ThisStartingPosition, LineByteArray + ThisStartingPosition + ThisWidth, CurrentColumnBytes);
                ResultMap[CurrentLine][i] = Format(CurrentColumnBytes, ThisWidth, DataType[i]);
            }
        }
        CurrentLine++;
    }
    std::cout << "Processed" << CurrentLine << " lines in : " << duration_cast<double>(sw.elapsed()) << '\n';
```

I still am a little disappointed because using the Boost Gregorian calendar conversion is unavailable using Clang to compile, and using the standard MS compiler makes it nearly 20X slower. With `Clang -O3` it was processing 10,700 records in 0.25 seconds including all `int` and `string` conversions. I will just have to write my own `date` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the commands being executed in assembler/machine code. VS has never been great at C++ and for many years Borland kicked their arses for both efficiency & reliability. Then Borland sold their IDE & C++ branch as a separate company.

It also depends on how you have programmed the process to occur in C++, can you please edit to show that code?

The advantage of C# is that it is managed and may use higher level of interpretations of your code, so in the background it may JIT the code into converting the whole line to the parsed format, then the for loop breaks the chunks off *(1 step looped)*, wheras if you write it in C++ it will follow your commands more accurately even if they are less efficient, ie: it breaks off the chunk you are looking at, then converts that to the parsed format *(2 steps looped)*.

So using the above example if we assume the 2 commands together are 50% slower than the 2 commands in C++, but the 2 commands are being processed on every loop, where the c# code only processeds the 1 command on every loop, any inefficiency will be compounded.

ALSO +1 to doug in comments above, reference vs value can make a pretty big difference especially when you are dealing with large datasets. I think his answer is the most likely for large differences.

Simplification is the answer I believe:

```
std::string byteString = hex.substr(i, 2);
unsigned char byte = (unsigned char) strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

Could become

```
unsigned char byte = (unsigned char) strtol(hex.substr(i, 2).c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

and remove a minor memory assignment. But again, if you can convert the entire source to a byte stream, then use the for loop on that, you remove the conversion step from the loop.

Comment: Thanks Slipoch, Did you see the link to the full C++ code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/VIvardJNAMKzSbMf? The relevant lines are on the main page from 48-85

Comment: Yeah just saw that, I would definitely look at using references instead of values in any function calls and when dealing with the data. I would also recommend simplifying each part of the process or seeing if you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly will. The stopwatch isn't timing that particular area, but the idea is still great. I haven't ever worked with the pointers, but hope to learn how to use them for this tonight.

Comment: Ah I used to be good at pointers. Been using C# for so long now, that I have mostly forgotten all the info I had on using them.